# Mobile load testing

Tags: mobile, jmeter

Weather it is required to do load test for MOBILE APPLICATIONS ?
My application is basically of client server application, load testing is really matter in mobile applications ?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it matters but its not a compulsion. its good to test application under load but not mandatory (If you must have some magic to handle server crash or low response/throughput).

Answer (score 1):

You can load test the web-services (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Load testing of mobile application really matters. You can test using below approach.

```
1) Load test the server side. This way you can understand whether the server(s) can handle the load for specific time duration.
2) During load test, you can test your app in the mobile manually.Then, you can get some understanding about the app performance from client side.
```